# Is there a way to search for text in package in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, search, text, package

I usually search for things in Eclipse with ctrl+H. This only allows me to search for text based on file name extensions though. Ctrl+F seems to only search the current document. Is there a way to search text within a package?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Click on the package in Package Explorer, then hit Ctrl-H and click 'Selected Resources'

Comment: Sure does!  Do I get love too? :)

Comment: This is very useful question and answer. Reason is that in big projects, as a developer we are tend to forget the starting point of some class or service etc. For that case. we can use this option. Thank you dfb and Bluebomber357 !